# event.preventDefault() not working with jQuery mobile?

Tags: jquery, events, jquery-mobile, anchor

Some really simple code:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#promotional-page', function(){
    $(".win-anchor").on('vmousedown', function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

Why does it still redirect to the linked page?

Comment: Are you sure it's the `vmousedown` event that's firing? There could be another event you also need to prevent.

Comment: `pagebeforeshow` have you tried with `pageinit`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/y5jyt/

This will work cross platform.

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#promotional-page', function(){       
    $(document).on('vmousedown click', '.win-anchor',function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        return false;
    });
});
```